# Same data returned in multiple requests submitted at same time (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue where locally or pushed out to production that if I submit the request in 2 different browsers (e.g. chrome and firefox), I am returned data from the first request into the 2nd. I don't use threading, nor static variables. I have a solution that consists of

- Data
- Domain
- Service
- Web

The Web project calls a service function, that uses EF4 from an EDMX file. For some reason multiple requests hitting the server at the same time is returning data from the first request. Now we currently have 6 developers looking at this. The parameters are unique and not passing the wrong ones. I am looking for any introspection into maybe it's something inherent that we don't fully understand in the framework. For example we are using:

- Ninject
- AutoMapper
- EF4

This is a very strange issue that is baffling us and if you have read this far, hard to explain.

Comment: caching based on incomplete/wrong set of parameters?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't cache any of the data.

Comment: Can you post your Ninject setup code? Particularly the EF/Data parts, if you use it for that.